# Vue one file, echarts error xAxis "0" not found

Tags: vue.js, echarts

I'm new to Vue and also echarts.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-charts-and-graphs-to-a-vue-js-application-29f943a45d09/

Until I can run my "npm run serve" command.
I opend up my localhost, but the diagram just not there.
I got an error in console which says: Error: xAxis "0" not found
Am I missing something? My code looks like the same as the tutorial.

Comment: file: `@/plugins/echarts.js`, change `import 'echarts/lib/chart/bar';` to `import * as echarts from 'echarts';`. And if you're using eslint, add `// eslint-disable-next-line` before it.

Answer (score 10):

Are you using the v5.x of echarts? If so, then you need to import `GridComponent` as well. Refer to this [issue](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts/issues/528) on github.

Answer (score 0):

with vue3
import {
...
GridComponent
} from 'echarts/components';

use([
...
GridComponent
]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).